# How to use nebular with angular?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am following https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/create-nebular-page#create-nebular-page for creating a nebular page but it is throwing multiple errors like below:

```
01: 'nb-sidebar' is not a known element:
    1. If 'nb-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'nb-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    
    4   <nb-sidebar>Sidebar Content</nb-sidebar>
```

I've created a module and when i go to that page it works fine for some random text but when i add nebular code it throw errors.

Code used in component html:

```
<nb-layout>
  <nb-layout-header fixed>Company Name</nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar>Sidebar Content</nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    Page Content <button nbButton>Hello World</button>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { NbSidebarModule, NbLayoutModule, NbButtonModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NbIconModule } from '@nebular/theme';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbSidebarModule,
    NbButtonModule,
    NbIconModule,
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

app module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NbThemeModule, NbLayoutModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';
import { NbSidebarModule} from '@nebular/theme';

import { DashboardComponent } from './pages/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbEvaIconsModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: declarations: [DashboardComponent ], <-- You have to add your component there.
If it is registered in multiple places you maybe have to import/export modules

Comment: What does the AppModule look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to the **AppModule**:

```
imports: [
    // ...
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

And, as you have already done, add the `NbSidebarModule` to your feature module.  See [NbSidebarComponent](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/sidebar/overview#nbsidebarcomponent)

Comment: Thanks that is working. But now i am getting same errors for EvaIcons:                                              'nb-icon' is not a known element:
    1. If 'nb-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
I have edited Question for the same.

Comment: I will mark it up, i can really appreciate if you can help.
For every module i am adding i get this error for example, i added nb-card and i got 'nb-card' is not a known element:.

In nebular docs they ask to add NbCardModule in imports and i did that but there is error persists, may be i am missing out on something you can tell.

Comment: It looks like NbCard only needs to be added to the feature module, as per the docs.  Which module have you added NbCard to?